# Confused on Python for loop behavior and if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was hoping someone could explain this behaviour to me and what is going on.

If I run the following code:

```
phrase = "Don't Panic!"
phraseList = list(phrase)
print(phrase)
print(phraseList)

ontap = ['o', 'n', 't', 'a', 'p']

for letter in phraseList:
    print("Letter ", letter)
    #if letter not in ontap:
    #    phraseList.remove(letter)

print(phraseList)
```

I get the following expected output:

```
Don't Panic!
['D', 'o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'P', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
Letter  D
Letter  o
Letter  n
Letter  '
Letter  t
Letter   
Letter  P
Letter  a
Letter  n
Letter  i
Letter  c
Letter  !
['D', 'o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'P', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
```

However if I remove the comments I get this unexpected behaviour:

```
Don't Panic!
['D', 'o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'P', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
Letter  D
Letter  n
Letter  '
Letter   
Letter  a
Letter  n
Letter  i
Letter  !
['o', 'n', 't', 'P', 'a', 'n', 'c']
```

So my question is, in the loop I would expect `PRINT` to be performed first before the list. `remove` function runs but it doesn't seem to work that way. Why? It seems to be skipping letters in the print like the letter C.
Also why does the compare seem to ignore the letter C when it clearly isn't in the `ontap` variable.

I am probably missing something extremely obvious. Does it have something to do with resizing the list and running a loop on it at the same time?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: that's because you modified the length of the list, but not the index which was supposed to be printed,. when letter is `D` it removed d, but now the internal index was still 1 and in the new `phraselist` `on't panic!` so it printed n

Comment: Yeah, so you don't want to remove items from something you're iterating because it throws off the iterator. I tend to use list comprehension to construct a new list with the items I want to keep, but one could also iterate a copy and remove items from the original.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments on the question confirm, the problem is indeed modifying `phraseList` while iterating over it. In a bit more detail, what's happening is this: when you go into the for loop, an iterator is created to iterate over `phraseList`. In the first iteration, the iterator supplies `phraseList[0]`, which is `D`. This is not in the `ontap` list, so we do `phraseList.remove('D')`. On the next iteration, `phraseList` is now `['o', 'n', "'", 't', ...]`, but the iterator doesn't know it's changed - it just knows that now it needs to supply `phraseList[1]`, which is now `n`. This is why the second iteration prints `n`, rather than `o`. `c` is never removed from `phraseList` because the only place it occurs is right after the first time `i` appears. When `i` is removed from `phraseList`, on the next loop, `c` is skipped. (Similarly, `P` is not removed because it's right after the first instance of `<space>`.)

The simplest way to fix your loop would be to iterate over a copy of `phraseList`:

```
for letter in list(phraseList):
    print("Letter ", letter)
    if letter not in ontap:
        phraseList.remove(letter)
```

This way changing the original `phraseList` doesn't affect the iteration. You could also be more concise (and, in my opinion, more clear) with a list comprehension. The following accomplishes exactly what the for loop above does:

```
phraseList = [letter for letter in phraseList if letter in ontap]
```